# Hosting an "IP Rental" address. Is this common, safe?

Tags: network

I have a supposed opportunity to get in with an individual with advertising and a side business of his, renting IP addresses. He has asked me to set a dedicated DSL account at my house. Is there any risk for me? I have other devices on a separate DSL account and modem. I'm a novice at networking and not too advanced on computers, just wondering what my risks are, if any, of him taking advantage of me, due to the amount of scammers and hackers?

Comment: Run Like The Wind.

Comment: I have this pile of horse manure that smells sweeter... Read your TOS

Comment: At least he asked before messing everything up :)

Answer (score 37):

Yes, there is significant risk to you. The value of allowing someone else to "rent" access to a DSL connection at *your* house is so that they can pretend to be you in their online behavior. If it's your name and address on the agreement with the ISP, then typically you're the one responsible for what happens on that connection. Actual legal liability varies by locality, but your exposure it typically pretty significant.

There have been several instances all over the world (Austria, Germany, USA, and others) where individuals have been arrested and charged because of illegal traffic (usually child porn) going through their Internet connection (typically TOR exit nodes).

Whatever this individual is planning, there's a decent chance that it will end up with you in jail.

Comment: Agreed. But here's a twist: contact a local law enforcement agency (police, FBI, etc) and work with them to do a "sting". That way you will avoid jail, if it goes bad then you're doing a good thing, and if it happens to be innocent (and profitable) you might still make a few pennies.

Comment: @AviD: While usually the law enforcement services will be suportive in such circumstances there are lots of documented cases where the 'mole' got screwed too.

Comment: @symcbean sure, there is always a risk, but if done right (depending on locale), with proper documentation etc should be safe at least from the law. He should probably talk to a lawyer first, though...

Comment: Wouldn't the better option be to avoid the possibility in the first place? Sure, be a mole if you are already in the situation and need to CYA on the way out... but why put yourself into the position in the first place? Unless the payout is worth the risk, and you can live with the worst case scenario: Roommate who thinks you sure do have a perdy mouth.

Comment: @AviD Can, and do you want to, squeal like a pig?  If not, you're playing with fire.

Comment: Ahh, "do the right thing", "lock up all the child molesters", "lets protect our children" - meh, what do I know, better to play it safe and lock yourself in an underground lair.

Comment: Just to provide further reading, [here are some things to consider](https://blog.torproject.org/running-exit-node) if you're still on the fence after reading @tylerl's answer.  Unless you're prepared to be on even shakier ground than a TOR exit node (which people have at least heard about before), don't do it.

Comment: By all means, advise caution, but this answer is overstating the risks sufficiently to make it almost completely wrong, if I may say so.

Comment: @MarcksThomas overstatement you say? Can you point to a single aspect of the answer which hasn't happened to someone already?

Answer (score 14):

Ask yourself this question:

Why is this individual asking YOU to set this up, at your house, under your name, instead of doing it himself, under his own name, at his own property?

Don't like what just came to mind? Good, you shouldn't.

The basic scam predates the internet, and what is going on is that this individual is essentially using your identity, person and property as a mule. Think drug smuggling if you'd like to draw a more direct analogy, but bear in mind, if this person engages in illicit activity, it's YOUR door the police will be breaking down.

YOUR name is on the contract, the line is at YOUR house, and YOU agreed to let this person do... whatever they were going to do. Frankly I cannot imagine any compensation they'd be willing to pay (Millions of $ would be insufficient) would compensate you for the risk they pose to you.

Cut your ties to this person immediately and count yourself lucky to have sought informed advice.